cs"} is not working when nvim-surround is installed via LazyVim
I added nvim-surround like follows in ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins :
return {
  "kylechui/nvim-surround",
  version = "*", -- Use for stability; omit to use `main` branch for the latest features
  event = "VeryLazy",
  config = function()
    require("nvim-surround").setup({
      -- Configuration here, or leave empty to use defaults
      -- keymaps = {
      --   insert = "<C-g>s",
      --   insert_line = "<C-g>S",
      --   normal = "ys",
      --   normal_cur = "yss",
      --   normal_line = "yS",
      --   normal_cur_line = "ySS",
      --   visual = "S",
      --   visual_line = "gS",
      --   delete = "ds",
      --   change = "cs",
      --   change_line = "cS",
      -- },
    })
  end,
}

LazyVim says nvim-surround loaded. But only one command is working on a visual selection: S with " ) etc
I am missing badly the replace command like cs"}. Do I have to read in the keymaps into the file .config/nvim/lua/config/keymaps.lua actively?
:LazyHealth shows up nearly no issues. But some overlapping keymaps:
- WARNING In mode `n`, <d> overlaps with <ds>:
  - <d>: delete
  - <ds>: Delete a surrounding pair

...

- WARNING In mode `n`, <y> overlaps with <yS>, <ySS>, <ys>, <yss>:
  - <y>: copy_to_clipboard
  - <yS>: Add a surrounding pair around a motion, on new lines (normal mode)
  - <ySS>: Add a surrounding pair around the current line, on new lines (normal mode)
  - <ys>: Add a surrounding pair around a motion (normal mode)
  - <yss>: Add a surrounding pair around the current line (normal mode)

...
- WARNING In mode `n`, <ys> overlaps with <yss>:
  - <ys>: Add a surrounding pair around a motion (normal mode)
  - <yss>: Add a surrounding pair around the current line (normal mode)



I can't reproduce the issue you're having, cs"} works fine for me while using your setup. Also :Lazy health output doesn't show any of the warnings you're showing here, so not sure what's going on there. Is it possible you have another plug-in that's creating interference? Perhaps try a setup with nvim-surround only and see if that works for you?

Thx for editing and commenting my question. After heavy testing I got it working, adding a g modifier in front of the keymaps:       ```
keymaps = {
insert = "s",
insert_line = "S",
normal = "gys",
normal_cur = "gyss",
normal_line = "gyS",
normal_cur_line = "gySS",
visual = "S",
visual_line = "gS",
delete = "gds",
change = "gcs",
change_lineg = "gcS",
} - perhaps I should answer my own question here on the bottom?

I needed to modify my keymaps, like follows. Finally my nvim-surround is working with the g modifier in front of the keymaps. Modified file in ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/nvim-surround.lua:
return {
  "kylechui/nvim-surround",
  version = "*", -- Use for stability; omit to use `main` branch for the latest features
  event = "VeryLazy",
  config = function()
    require("nvim-surround").setup({
      -- Configuration here, or leave empty to use defaults
      -- Comp <https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/45454/cs-is-not-working-when-nvim-surround-is-installed-via-lazyvim>
      -- Test on 2024-09-01 - Added modifier `g` in front of the commands
      keymaps = {
        insert = "<C-g>s",
        insert_line = "<C-g>S",
        normal = "gys",
        normal_cur = "gyss",
        normal_line = "gyS",
        normal_cur_line = "gySS",
        visual = "S",
        visual_line = "gS",
        delete = "gds",
        change = "gcs",
        change_lineg = "gcS",
      },
    })
  end,
}

Hope this will help some beginners to LazyVim like me!
